# Disable swipe gesture from opening the navigation drawer using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation (https://reactnavigation.org) and I am trying to disable the option that the side drawer opens when the user swipes right/left

I`ve looked through the documentation and i cant find the options that does the trick

```
const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    Components: {
      screen: Components
    },
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    headerMode: 'none',
    contentComponent: SideBar,
    contentOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    }
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      'Montserrat-Light': require("./app/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf"),
      'Montserrat-Medium': require("./app/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf")
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <Text>Loading</Text>
      );
    }
    return (
      <RootStack/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`drawerLockMode`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#drawerlockmode) in the screen navigation options using the option `locked-open`

**locked-open**: `the drawer will stay opened and not respond to gestures. The drawer may still be opened and closed programmatically`

Other options can be viewed [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode)

```
static navigationOptions = {
     drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the drawer closed in the first screen, so i've added `drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'`  in:
`navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({          
          drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
          title: 'MainActivity',
          headerLeft : <HamburgerIcon navigationProps={ navigation }/>,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        })`
But is not working, what's wrong?. thanks

Comment: Note that you don't want to use `navigationOptions` but set it directly in the drawer options.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1082#issuecomment-411080810

Comment: Hey, @JamonHolmgren I've tried **locked Mode** I want to disable drawer swiping with other screens but doesn't work!

Comment: You are amazing sir! Thank you @pritish

Comment: What if I want to prevent gestures from opening the drawer, but allow swipe to close the drawer?

Comment: @DrorBar try this  `disableGestures: true` you can check my answer

Answer (score 19):

Set **edge width** to 0.

### React Navigation 6

In screen options:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    swipeEdgeWidth: 0,
  }}
>
  {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

### React Navigation 5

In your createDrawerNavigator config:

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  }
}, 
{
  edgeWidth: 0
})
```

Comment: In addition, this answer is for react-navigation v5. Also not supported on Web [yet]

Answer (score 12):

In react-navigation v5, you can disable swiping gestures for a specific screen by passing `swipeEnabled: false`:

```
      <DrawerNavigator.Screen
        name='ScreenName'
        component={Screen}
        options={{
          swipeEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 9):

**React Navigation V5**

This version changed how we set the properties of the Navigation Drawer so the other answers will no longer work. Instead of setting the properties in

```
createDrawerNavigator()
```

Set them in the JSX tag like so

```
<Drawer.Navigator edgeWidth={0} >
```

This will disable swipe to open while keeping swipe to close enabled.

Comment: On some devices I was still able to swipe it open with edgeWidth={0}. It's safer to put -1.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to disable it,
it won't open but still can be closed by swiping...

this is my code

```
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  initialRouteName: 'Stack',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  drawerWidth: '80%',
  edgeWidth: -100 // this is where the magic happens :))
```

Answer (score 6):

**React Navigation v5:**

You can use `swipeEnabled:false` prop for your Drawer screen.

Example

```
<Drawer.Screen
   name="ExamplePage"
   component={ExampleComponent}
   options={{
       title: 'Example Page Title',
       swipeEnabled: false, // to disable swipe gesture for a specific page(s)
   }}
/>
```

Doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#swipeenabled

> From doc:
>
> Whether you can use swipe gestures to open or close the drawer.
> Defaults to true.
>
> Swipe gesture is not supported on Web.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, add `swipeEnabled: false` to the `screenOptions` property of `Navigator`.

#### Example:

```js
<DrawerOptionsNavigator.Navigator
    screenOptions={{swipeEnabled: false}} 
    // add swipeEnabled to false to disable the swipe gesture from all screens inside drawer
>
<DrawerOptionsNavigator.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={RootNavigator}
/>
</DrawerOptionsNavigator.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue solved using the following way

Disable/Enable gesture mode using `disableGestures: true`

**The drawer can be locked in 3 states:**

1. **unlocked** (default)- Meaning that the drawer will respond (open/close) to touch gestures.
2. **locked-closed**- Meaning that the drawer will stay closed and not respond to gestures.
3. **locked-open**- Meaning that the drawer will stay opened and not respond to gestures.

   `enum('unlocked', 'locked-closed', 'locked-open')`

The drawer may still be opened and closed programmatically (openDrawer/closeDrawer).

```
mainflow: createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    DrawerScreen2: DrawerScreen2,
    DrawerScreen3: DrawerScreen3,

    Notifications: {
        screen: Notifications,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            drawerLockMode: "locked-closed",
            disableGestures: true

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

inside `createDrawerNavigator` in v4 you need to add

```
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
       drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Idk if you are still looking for the answer. I had the same question and the only way I got to avoid the opening on swipe was the following.

Inside the drawer navigator you will have you screen, what you need to do is pass the "option" prop and inside that "swipeEnabled: false" to the screen you want to keep the drawer hidden, like this:

```
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="name"
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
    <Drawer.Screen
        name="name"
        component={component}
        options={{ swipeEnabled: false }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set **swipeEnabled** to false.

### React Navigation 6

In screen options:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }}
>
  {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the current React Navigation version 3.11.1, you can easily do so by adding drawerLockMode when create the drawer navigator. Change 'locked-open' to 'locked-closed' if you want to prevent gestures from opening the drawer but allow click on outside of drawer to close the drawer.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: MainStack,
    Driver: ManageRideTabStack,
    Passenger: ManageRequestTabStack,
    FeedbackPage: FeedbackStack,
}, {
    hideStatusBar: false,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
    overlayColor: '#9FF7B3',
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#fff',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#4DD0E1',
        labelStyle: {
           fontSize: 16,
        },
    },
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
});
```